# Difference between throw and throws in Java?

Tags: java, throw, throws

Can any one clearly state the difference between throw and throws in Java exception handling with an example? I have tried googling but couldn't arrive at a conclusion. Pls help

Comment: @suresh atta very funny

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. `throws` clause is used to declare an exception and `throw` keyword is used to throw an exception explicitly.
2. If we see syntax wise then `throw` is followed by an instance variable and `throws` is followed by exception class names.
3. The keyword `throw` is used inside method body to invoke an exception and `throws` clause is used in method declaration (signature).

For example

**throw**

```
throw new Exception("You have some exception")
throw new IOException("Connection failed!!")
```

**throws**

```
public int myMethod() throws IOException, ArithmeticException, NullPointerException {}
```

4. You cannot declare multiple exceptions with `throw`.    You can declare multiple exception e.g. public void method()throws IOException,SQLException.
5. checked exceptions can not be propagated with `throw` only because it is explicitly used to throw an particular exception.  checked exception can be propagated with `throws`.

**Exception propagation:** An exception propagates from method to method, up the call stack, until it's caught. So if a() calls b(), which calls c(), which calls d(), and if d() throws an exception, the exception will propagate from d to c to b to a, unless one of these methods catches the exception.
[what is exception propagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633664/what-is-exception-propagation)

Comment: By using Throw keyword in java you cannot throw more than one exception but using throws you can declare multiple exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

`throw` use for throwing actual `Exception` and `throws` declare at method it might throws `Exception`.

```
public int findMax(int[] array) throws Exception{
    if(array==null)
       throw new NullPointerException(...);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void someMethod(List<Foo> someList) throws SomeException { 
    if (someList.isEmpty()) throw new SomeException();
}
```