# Unreported exception java.lang.exception

Tags: java, try-catch

Unreported exception java.lang.exception : Must be caught or declared to be throw.
Why this problem will occur? Is it some simple method that can help to solve this problems?

I apply this code in my java..

```
public byte[] encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("ABCDEABCDE"
                    .getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    // String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
    // .encode(cipherText);

    return cipherText;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("ABCDEABCDE"
                    .getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
}
```

The error is shown in this below part

```
byte[] pass = encrypt(password);
String pw = new String(pass);
```

Any idea?
Im using java netbeans to do my project..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `encrypt()` method throws an `Exception`. This means that where you're calling this method, you should explictly throw this `Exception` or handle it using a `try-catch` block.

In your case, for this particular code:

```
byte[] pass = encrypt(password);
String pw = new String(pass);
```

You should either enclose it in:

```
try{
 byte[] pass = encrypt(password);
 String pw = new String(pass);
}catch(Exception exe){
 //Your error handling code
}
```

or declare the method where this code is enclosed with `throws Exception`.

- If you are new to exception handling, consider reading this: [Lesson: Exceptions from the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)
- Also, here's another interesting read on ["Guidelines on Exception propagation (in Java)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551221/guidelines-on-exception-propagation-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** There are **2 ways to handle the exception.**

```
 - Either `declare` it
 - or `Handle` it.
```

**2.** `encrypt()` method above **throws an Exception**

**So either declare it on the method declaration in which you are calling it.**

**eg:**

```
public void MyCallingMethod() throws Exception{

     byte[] pass = encrypt(password);
     String pw = new String(pass);


}
```

**Or handle it with** `try/catch` **block,** `finally` **is optional**

```
try{

     byte[] pass = encrypt(password);
     String pw = new String(pass);
   }catch(Exception ex){


  }
```