# Having a class handling all exceptions (MVC)?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm writing a program following completely the MVC design pattern, currently I have lots of methods that throw exceptions and I'm handling them poorly.

I thought of adding a class in the controller called `exceptionHandler`, which would have methods like `public void receiveRuntimeException(String message)`, `receiveAnotherTypeOfException(...)`, etc.

Then giving most classes (particularly those in the view) a reference to `exceptionHandler` and then whenever a methods throws an exception, do something like this

```
try{
    methodThatWillThrowAwfulException()
}catch(AwfulException e){
    exceptionHandler.receiveAwfulException("methodThatWillThrowAwfulException threw awful exception")
}
```

Is this a good practice? If not, how should exceptions be handled in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has the concept of [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes), in which you can annotate a class to handle various aspects, such as error handling (thus annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`). You may not use Spring yourself; this is a pattern that is being adopted by a very popular MVC framework.

In that vein, you should strive to make **as many methods as necessary** to handle **as many exceptions as necessary**. Do not create one method to handle an omni-exception, since you want your errors to be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551221/guidelines-on-exception-propagation-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I don't quite understand that controller advice annotation, what's it supposed to do? Do you think that the option I showed in the question is alright?

Answer (score 0):

You want to handling error? one controller. commonExceptionHandler?

(context.xml)

```
<!-- Exception Resolver -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultErrorView" value="exception/default"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="warnLogCategory" value="log"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

(web.xml)

```
<!-- error -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>301</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>304</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>307</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>402</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>406</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>415</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>429</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>501</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/exception/default.html</location>
</error-page>
```

(handler controller)

```
@ControllerAdvice("you.project.package")
public class CommonExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception){
        logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("exception/default");

        return mav;
    }
}
```

You can to search in google.

Try. after You come to show error and code.